# ffmpeg convert audio to ogg and keep album cover

Tags: ffmpeg, ogg

If I convert an audio file with an album cover thank's to:

```
ffmpeg -i sample1.flac -ar 48000 -vn -c:a libvorbis -b:a 320k sample1.ogg
```

My sample1.ogg file doesn't have any album cover. Is there a way to ask explicitly to `ffmpeg` to **keep the cover** ?

Comment: Bug [#4448 Properly support cover art in ogg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4448). You'll have to use some other tool to re-add the album/cover image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum up of answers I found: Remove the option `-vn` which means: no video, because thumbnail are frame of video. Use `libtheora` instead of `libvorbis`. If you get a bitrate error, remove option `-b:a 320k`. At the end we get:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flac -c:v libtheora -q:v 10 -c:a libvorbis file.ogg
```

This gives you a file with an audio and a video content.

If you prefer to extract thumbnail in a separate file (to re-add it later for example), use:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flac -an -vcodec copy thumbnail.jpg
```

Thank's to Баяр Гончикжапов for his help and answers!

Answer (score 3):

instead "-vn" write "-c:v libtheora -q:a 10".

-vn - means no video, picture is frame of video in ffmpeg

Comment: I understand! If I run this: `ffmpeg -i sample1.flac -ar 48000 -c:v copy libvorbis -b:a 320k sample1.ogg` I get `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libvorbis' libvorbis: Invalid argument`. I suppose it's because libvorbis can't handle it with vidéo option?

Comment: -c:v for video, -c:a for audio: `ffmpeg -i sample1.flac -ar 48000 -c:v copy -c:a libvorbis -b:a 320k sample1.ogg`

Comment: I get: `Unsupported codec id in stream 0. Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument. Error initializing output stream 0:1 --`

Comment: Shame on me. Maybe ogg doesn't support jpegs. You have to convert to theora: `ffmpeg -i sample1.flac -c:v libtheora -q:v 10 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 320k sample1.ogg`